How to correctly identify receiver address in solana transaction?
I'm trying to identify receiver in this solana transaction: 3vNRFq4pUkgj419ydC8cDDvZ1EcLaBoBPbKuawschysH822ivUR6qdihTKc2QjKtWcRkKk5Ry2z46RJ8PyCgHDaF
Inside this transaction address C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq received 6,200.7776 CHEEMS
But if I look inside transaction data - I see that receiver is R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq
Transaction data:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "slot": 106570637,
    "transaction": {
      "signatures": [
        "3vNRFq4pUkgj419ydC8cDDvZ1EcLaBoBPbKuawschysH822ivUR6qdihTKc2QjKtWcRkKk5Ry2z46RJ8PyCgHDaF"
      ],
      "message": {
        "header": {
          "numRequiredSignatures": 1,
          "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,
          "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 6
        },
        "accountKeys": [
          "C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq",
          "3uQn9uyUVcfNJWq8hQ3U3f1JgoUgmFA93f6wDxpo5Hhx",
          "2JNf5J5CYxRt4MVqF87eXzvtKYRcCMxh2irRrdkarwmR",
          "75zvHKY2NSNpkTEZNAaHUga6TGDbjdACAsdtFLULWQpR",
          "64pXm8wxXW8vYfFA72oLBQTB9NFSHs6atuk8ULiwYXnd",
          "9hEdNRRav5N2iwpJQFqEVKTo3UqoEzDTMjGQ5pXwgQe8",
          "671udjPkZTgGo2W6S5etTiR3xSicUsQekqYdDTTJ9XFy",
          "BaXrnp5Cwnf1FBoBtArkxsCJf2mwPLWGGnPWvBTKmsA2",
          "R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq",
          "HfWYVyu61NPM4rVLJEdqi1dX24kLoKtLAJE8x7Uof96s",
          "5RNN4QSB89aEjgWNj1p2EQu5mutveErSwX76EbdNtzwA",
          "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111",
          "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
          "4qzeLSiyNP7V81DCarJxkAMzx8sDydvZZEE26UgHet9J"
        ],
        "recentBlockhash": "FGS4MP5x1jskV1s9udc5qD4qAdjSMHQcx527adyu7Eqy",
        "instructions": [
          {
            "programIdIndex": 14,
            "accounts": [
              1,
              2,
              9,
              3,
              4,
              0,
              5,
              6,
              10,
              7,
              8,
              0,
              11,
              12,
              13
            ],
            "data": "EwUEhZsGL8ZpFYFhtDGJf9",
            "stackHeight": "None"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "meta": {
      "err": "None",
      "status": {
        "Ok": "None"
      },
      "fee": 5000,
      "preBalances": [
        52476320,
        3055440,
        1461600,
        2039280,
        2728320,
        2039280,
        2039280,
        2039280,
        2039280,
        0,
        0,
        1089991680,
        1169280,
        1009200,
        1141440
      ],
      "postBalances": [
        52471320,
        3055440,
        1461600,
        2039280,
        2728320,
        2039280,
        2039280,
        2039280,
        2039280,
        0,
        0,
        1089991680,
        1169280,
        1009200,
        1141440
      ],
      "innerInstructions": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "instructions": [
            {
              "programIdIndex": 11,
              "accounts": [
                3,
                8,
                9
              ],
              "data": "3rxDv9qXYp6B",
              "stackHeight": "None"
            },
            {
              "programIdIndex": 11,
              "accounts": [
                7,
                6,
                0
              ],
              "data": "3DTZbgwsozUF",
              "stackHeight": "None"
            },
            {
              "programIdIndex": 11,
              "accounts": [
                2,
                5,
                9
              ],
              "data": "6AjePwYNteRu",
              "stackHeight": "None"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "logMessages": [
        "Program 4qzeLSiyNP7V81DCarJxkAMzx8sDydvZZEE26UgHet9J invoke [1]",
        "Program log: current timestamp: 1636755380",
        "Program log: last_reward_block: 1636754227",
        "Program log: Acc token per share: 85889640",
        "Program log: Pending reward: 62007776",
        "Program log: Transfer pending reward from reward to depositor wallet",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
        "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3121 of 175200 compute units",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
        "Program log: Transfer token from depositor to stake vault",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
        "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3121 of 168430 compute units",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
        "Program log: Mint proof of staking tokens",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
        "Program log: Instruction: MintTo",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2779 of 161772 compute units",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
        "Program 4qzeLSiyNP7V81DCarJxkAMzx8sDydvZZEE26UgHet9J consumed 47275 of 200000 compute units",
        "Program 4qzeLSiyNP7V81DCarJxkAMzx8sDydvZZEE26UgHet9J success"
      ],
      "preTokenBalances": [
        {
          "accountIndex": 3,
          "mint": "3FoUAsGDbvTD6YZ4wVKJgTB76onJUKz7GPEBNiR5b8wc",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 25813330.1872,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "258133301872",
            "uiAmountString": "25813330.1872"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 5,
          "mint": "2JNf5J5CYxRt4MVqF87eXzvtKYRcCMxh2irRrdkarwmR",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 0.749854934,
            "decimals": 9,
            "amount": "749854934",
            "uiAmountString": "0.749854934"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 6,
          "mint": "oMj5c7gAEnwysNmFyfZfKyMs2rsFdV2FXuCuGxW3W6R",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 74985.4934,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "749854934",
            "uiAmountString": "74985.4934"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 7,
          "mint": "oMj5c7gAEnwysNmFyfZfKyMs2rsFdV2FXuCuGxW3W6R",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 0.0001,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "1",
            "uiAmountString": "0.0001"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 8,
          "mint": "3FoUAsGDbvTD6YZ4wVKJgTB76onJUKz7GPEBNiR5b8wc",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": "None",
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "0",
            "uiAmountString": "0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "postTokenBalances": [
        {
          "accountIndex": 3,
          "mint": "3FoUAsGDbvTD6YZ4wVKJgTB76onJUKz7GPEBNiR5b8wc",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 25807129.4096,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "258071294096",
            "uiAmountString": "25807129.4096"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 5,
          "mint": "2JNf5J5CYxRt4MVqF87eXzvtKYRcCMxh2irRrdkarwmR",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 0.749854934,
            "decimals": 9,
            "amount": "749854934",
            "uiAmountString": "0.749854934"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 6,
          "mint": "oMj5c7gAEnwysNmFyfZfKyMs2rsFdV2FXuCuGxW3W6R",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 74985.4934,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "749854934",
            "uiAmountString": "74985.4934"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 7,
          "mint": "oMj5c7gAEnwysNmFyfZfKyMs2rsFdV2FXuCuGxW3W6R",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 0.0001,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "1",
            "uiAmountString": "0.0001"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 8,
          "mint": "3FoUAsGDbvTD6YZ4wVKJgTB76onJUKz7GPEBNiR5b8wc",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "uiAmount": 6200.7776,
            "decimals": 4,
            "amount": "62007776",
            "uiAmountString": "6200.7776"
          }
        }
      ],
      "rewards": [],
      "loadedAddresses": {
        "writable": [],
        "readonly": []
      }
    },
    "version": "legacy",
    "blockTime": 1636755380
  },
  "id": 0
}

I tryed to interpret data, and can see that receiver is R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq
Also I found that only this explorer: https://solana.fm/tx/3vNRFq4pUkgj419ydC8cDDvZ1EcLaBoBPbKuawschysH822ivUR6qdihTKc2QjKtWcRkKk5Ry2z46RJ8PyCgHDaF can show correctly real receiver. For example this one https://solscan.io/tx/3vNRFq4pUkgj419ydC8cDDvZ1EcLaBoBPbKuawschysH822ivUR6qdihTKc2QjKtWcRkKk5Ry2z46RJ8PyCgHDaF show the same as data in block: receiver is R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq.
Question: how linked this two addresses: R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq and C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq ? And how its possible to define that in this transaction real receiver is C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq ?

I think if you check the block explorer again, your doubts may clear out by themselves. As I can see on the Tx hash the C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq is the signer and R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq is the receiver.

Yes, in this explorer Tx hash we can see R3yZpx2Gcnc4Xw1RuJVQwWsb7GqodGpdzKK9QgZeNLq as the receiver, the same in info from transaction data. But here the receiver is C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq. And also if we try to grab all transactions for C9rD5HpmEEnDSTy7QASPaqF6i3mVtc5FWHYVFUHVhtuq - the balance for CHEEMS will be negative (-6,200.7776)
